# How to add background on ag grid pinnedBottomRowData using rowClass in aggrid angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How to add background in `pinnedBottomRowData` the entire bottom Row

here's the code

***list.component.ts***

```
  columnDefs = new Array();
  rowData = new Array();
  pinnedBottomRowData: any;
ngOnInit() {
this.columnDefs = [
      {
        'headerName': 'Style/Machine',
        'field': 'total',
      }
    ];
    for (let i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
      this.rowData.push(
        {
          'total': 'Machine ' + i
        }
      );
    }
    this.pinnedBottomRowData = this.createData(1);
}

  createData(count: number) {
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      result.push({
        total: 'Total Machine'
      },
        {
          total: 'Total',
        });
    }
    return result;
  }
```

here's the output
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can use `getRowStyle` and check if the row is pinned and at the bottom. Please refer the below example.

```
this.getRowStyle = function(params) {
      if (params.node.rowPinned === 'bottom') {
        return { "background-color": "blue" };
      }
    };
    this.pinnedBottomRowData = createData(1, "Bottom");
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6smfRzsNnDdzL8c4E1mC?p=preview)

Reference [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/)